# How to remove a mounted volume icon on the desktop?

Tags: mount, icons, usb-drive

Each time my 3G Vodafone k4505 Pen get's mounted by the system, I get a icon on my desktop.
I would like to NOT have that icon each time I connect this 3g usb pen.

How can we accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press Alt-F2 and enter `gconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to apps/nautilus/desktop.
3. Deselect volumes_visible.

[image: gconf-editor]

If you want your other volumes to be visible, you will have to add them manually:

1. Right click on desktop and click 'Create Launcher...'
2. Change the type to 'Location'
3. Change the name to suit you.
4. Browse for the volume.
5. Change the icon to the 'block device' icon at `/usr/share/icons/YOUR_THEME/devices/48/block-device.svg`
6. Click OK.

[image: launcher]

Comment: That will disable all other volumes that we may want as well right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to manually add the ones you want.

Comment: Amazing :) You absolutely rock. Second Ubuntu day here, but feeling the power already. :) Thanks.